# Libetpan not build on iOS5.1 xcode4.3 in ReMail App

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

Libetpan is not generating the binaries folder on xcode 5.1. I updated the `build-all-deps.sh` file

```
SDKLIST="5.1"
GCC_VERSION="4.2"
PLATFORMDIR="/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/${platform}.platform"
```

still not able to generate the binaries.

Error I am getting is:

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/reMail.app/reMail normal i386
cd "/Users/gauri/Spark/user/gauri_shankar@chat.softprodigy.local/downloads/ReMailiPhone/remail-iphone"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk "-L/Users/gauri/Spark/user/gauri_shankar@chat.softprodigy.local/downloads/ReMailiPhone/remail-iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-L/Users/gauri/Spark/user/gauri_shankar@chat.softprodigy.local/downloads/ReMailiPhone/remail-iphone" -L/Users/gauri/Downloads/x2on-OpenSSL-for-iPhone-9754b8d -L/Binaries/iPhoneSimulator-4.3/lib "-L/Users/gauri/Spark/user/gauri_shankar@chat.softprodigy.local/downloads/ReMailiPhone/remail-iphone/../mailcore/libetpan/build-mac/build/Debug" "-F/Users/gauri/Spark/user/gauri_shankar@chat.softprodigy.local/downloads/ReMailiPhone/remail-iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Users/gauri/Spark/user/gauri_shankar@chat.softprodigy.local/downloads/ReMailiPhone/remail-iphone/build/ReMailIPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReMail.build/Objects-normal/i386/reMail.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -all_load -ObjC -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -letpan-iphone -letpan /Users/gauri/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20.a /Users/gauri/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20Core.a /Users/gauri/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20Network.a /Users/gauri/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20Style.a /Users/gauri/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20UI.a /Users/gauri/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20UICommon.a /Users/gauri/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20UINavigator.a "/Users/gauri/Spark/user/gauri_shankar@chat.softprodigy.local/downloads/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MailCore/MailCore" -framework libetpan -framework QuartzCore "/Users/gauri/Spark/user/gauri_shankar@chat.softprodigy.local/downloads/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libmailcore.a" -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MessageUI -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -framework CoreLocation -framework AddressBook -framework StoreKit -framework CFNetwork -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -lsasl2 -lcrypto -lssl -o "/Users/gauri/Spark/user/gauri_shankar@chat.softprodigy.local/downloads/ReMailiPhone/remail-iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/reMail.app/reMail"
Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Please help me out.